# How to get max number from array key matching a pattern

Tags: php, regex, arrays, array-key

I have an array

```
$_images['image[1]'] = image1.jpg
$_images['image[2]'] = image2.jpg
$_images['image[3]'] = image3.jpg
$_images['image[4]'] = image4.jpg
```

How do I find the max number/ count in the key is 4 which matches a pattern image[].

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `count(preg_grep('/pattern/', $your_array))`?

Comment: you want to get the max key from _images[image[?]] ?

Comment: what does $_images[image[1]] even mean!?

Comment: @mark-b preg_grep is exactly what I was looking !! How do I select your answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marc B !

count(preg_grep('/images[([0-9]+)]/', $_images));

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're asking but if you mean

```
$_images[1] = 'image1.jpg';
$_images[2] = 'image2.jpg';
$_images[3] = 'image3.jpg';
$_images[4] = 'image4.jpg';
```

Then just do `echo count($_images);`

If you mean

```
$images[1] = 'image1.jpg';
$images[2] = 'image2.jpg';
$images[3] = 'image3.jpg';
$images[4] = 'image4.jpg';

$_images = array();
array_push($_images, $images); //array of arrays
```

then do

```
echo count($_images, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - 1; //keep in mind your parent array must only have 1 array inside it, or you have to do -x where x = number of your second-level arrays
```

If you mean something else, then you have to explain more...